# How to program an Arduino with I2C for a liquid crystal LCD screen?

Tags: arduino, lcd

I am trying to get text characters to come up on my liquid crystal LCD screen. It's a 16x2 screen. It only uses four pins... GND, 5 V, SCL, and SDA pins. I'm not sure how to program it since all I'm finding online is how to program it if my screen has 16 pins to connect for programming. I believe the address for my LCD screen is 0x27.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://arduino.cc/playground/Code/LCDi2c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this page on the Arduino playground](http://arduino.cc/playground/Code/LCDi2c) that has some libraries for certain LCD I2C displays.

Your specific model may not have an Arduino library for it.